# Cyclotomic Fields over Q and prime ideals 

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

**Q** is the rational number field.
p is a prime number.
q is a prime number other than p.
$k_{p^r}$ is a cyclotomic field.
$k_{p^r}$=**Q**(x) where x is exp(2$\pi$i/$p^r$).
[$k_{p^r}$:**Q**]=$p^{r-1}(p-1)$.

Question: Does q remain a prime in the integer ring of $k_{p^r}$?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Theorem I.2.13 of Washington's book on cyclotomic fields says the following: $K$ is the $n$th cyclotomic field and $p\nmid n$, let $f$ be the smallest positive integer such that $p^f\equiv 1 (\mathrm{mod}~n)$. Then $p$ splits into $\phi(n)/f$ distinct primes in $K$.

Comment: To match the notation here with the notation of the question, set $n := p^r$ and $p:=q$.  Short version of answer: Yes iff $\phi(p^r)/f = 1$.

Comment: Thanks, Scott. I had to run so I just quickly wrote up the statement.

Answer (score 6):

Not necessarily. Simplest case, $p=2$, $r=2$, so the integer ring is ${\bf Z}[i]$, and $q$ stays prime if and only if it's 3 (mod 4). Any algebraic number theory text should tell you lots about this question, e.g., Marcus, Number Fields.

Answer (score 2):

No. E.g., $p=2$, $r=2$ gives you the extension $\mathbb{Q}(i)$ with ring of integers $\mathbb{Z}[i]$. The prime 2 ramifies in this extension, and those congruent to 1 mod 4 split into two distinct prime ideals of $\mathbb{Z}[i]$. The only ones that remain prime (the terminology is *inert*) are those congruent to 3 mod 4.

Comment: Ha. Beat you by one minute. 

Comment: Yup, you did :)

Answer (score 2):

Only if it satisfies a congruence condition. The Frobenius for q in the Galois group is the determining condition, and inert primes are those for which it is a generator.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the congruence condition?  The Galois group for $k_{p^r}$/**Q** is a cyclic group. Do you mean the condition that q does not divide p-1?

Comment: The behaviour of a prime q depends only on the order of the cyclic subgroup it generates in that (multiplicative) group. The generators of the whole group mark out certain residue classes, and so the q are those that lie in certain arithmetic progressions.

Answer (score 1):

Yes if multiplicative order of $q$ modulo $p^r$ equals to $(p-1)p^{r-1}$.

Comment: This seems to echo Rob Harron's answer (all the more since there is no '$n$' in the question; cf. what Scott Carnahan wrote in his comment).

Comment: Thx for your comment. I have editted.